# How to create and write to multiple files in Python?

Tags: python

I have a for loop in Python and in every iteration I would like to write the result to a new text file.

```
import numpy as np

n = 5
g = my_func()
for i in range(n):
    """ I wan to have test0.txt for i = 0
    test1.txt for i = 1 and so on ...
    """
    f = open('test.txt','ab')
    np.savetxt(f, g, fmt='%.0f', newline=" ")
f.close()
```

Is this possible?

My real value of `n` is `1000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format) to create the string for the filename

```
f = open('test{}.txt'.format(i), 'ab')
```

So your code could be modified to

```
import numpy as np
n = 5
g = my_func()
for i in range(n):
    with open('test{}.txt'.format(i), 'ab') as f:
        np.savetxt(f, g, fmt='%.0f', newline=" ")
```